# Account Hierarchy - Trigger - Update All Accounts in Hierarchy

Tags: apex, account, trigger, hierarchy

I have following requirement in hand -

Update each account's field count__c in the Account Hierarchy.

where count__c = Count_of_Custom_Object_Records on Account + count from all Accounts who are child of Custom_Objects Parent Account.

**Example :**

```
              Acc1
            /     \
           /       \
          Acc2      Acc3
         /    \
        /      \
       Acc4     Acc5 
        |         | 
        |         |
   CustObjRec11    CustObjRec13--->Newly Inserted 
   CustObjRec12
```

**Also --Acc1 , Acc2, Acc3 can also have  one CustObjRecords each**!!

Now, I have value in count__c as below -

*(VALUES MANUALLY ENTERED / HAVE ONLY COUNT OF CustObjRecords of itself -Not added Child Accounts CustObjRecords)*

Acc1 : 1

Acc2 : 1

Acc3 : 1

Acc4 : 2

Acc5 : 0

if I have above hierarchy with given counts - and I inserted new **"CustObjRec13"** for **Acc5**

then  updated Count__c should be

Acc1 : 6= 1 + 4 + 1   (1 of Itself + 4 of Acc2 + 1 of Acc3)

Acc2 : 4 = 1 + 2 + 1  (1 of Itself + 2 of Acc4 + 1 of Acc5)

Acc3 : 1

Acc4 : 2

Acc5 : 1

**Code I am trying** (Excuse typo -if any)
**
**

> 1)    I can't use Rollup summary fields. (there is some sort of business
>   reason)
>   2) I need to do this by writing trigger on "CustObjRecord"
>   ONLY.

**

```
>     ** Few Parents are getting updated (upto 2 level - but in certain situations only) ------but not all accounts in hierarchy.
>     ** Getting 101 SOQL if try to call "getTopParentAccount" method.
```

**

```
  public with sharing class CustObjRecordTriggerHelper1 {

    public boolean flag;
    public static List<Account> accountHierarchyList = new List<Account>();
    public static Map<ID,Account> accountDetailsMap = new Map<ID,Account>();    
    public static Map<ID,List<Account>> parentChildLinkedListMap = new Map<ID,List<Account>>();
    public static Map<ID,Integer> accountIdLevelMap = new Map<ID,Integer>();
    public static Decimal totalcount;
    public void updateNoOfCustObjRecord(){

        try{

            Map<Account,List<CustObjRecord__c>> mapAccountCustObjRecord = new Map<Account,List<CustObjRecord__c>>();
            Map<ID,ID> Child_To_TopAccount=new Map<ID,ID>();
            List<Account> lstAccounttoUpdate = new List<Account>();
            List<Account> lstAcc1 = new List<Account>();
            Set<ID> setParentAccID = new Set<ID>();
            Integer finalCount=0;


           //Store Accounts Id's in set for all Triggered CustObjRecord
            for(CustObjRecord__c objRef : (List<CustObjRecord__c>)Trigger.new){
                 setParentAccID.add(objRef.CustObjRecord_By__c);
                /*if(objRef.Referred_By__r.ParentID !=null){
                    Child_To_TopAccount.put(objRef.Referred_By__c,objRef.Referred_By__r.ParentId);
                }
                */
            }

            /* Generate a Map which will store Account and its Lists of referrals
            //Query only Account (and all its child Referrals) who are immediate parent of Triggered Referral records
            */
            List<Account> listAccount = [SELECT id,count__c, (SELECT id,referral__c,Referred_By__c FROM CustObjRecords__r) FROM Account WHERE ID IN :setParentAccID];
            for(Account objAccount : listAccount){
                mapAccountReferral.put(objAccount, objAccount.CustObjRecords__r);            
            }
            System.Debug('----mapAccountCustObjRecord--'+mapAccountCustObjRecord);

            //Store Child - top Parent id's --- only those who has parent
            //**Child_TopAccount= getTopParentAccount(setParentAccID);

            for(Account acc: mapAccountCustObjRecord.keySet()){

                    /***** Get Count of Each immediate Account till topAccount. 
                     *
                     */

                    /***** GOT count of Top Parent Account
                    //Get the Top Parent Account of an Triggered Account -- and count for the same.
                    Account topAccountID=null;
                    topAccountID = Child_TopAccount.get(acc.id);
                    if(topAccountID==null){
                            topAccountID=acc.ID;
                    }
                    Decimal totalcount = getCountofCustObjRecord(topAccountID);
                        acc.count__c= totalcount;
                        lstAccounttoUpdate.add(acc);
                    */


                    // **** Get Count of Triggered Account and its childs 
                    //Self and immediate Childs count storing method call
                    totalcount = getCountofCustObjRecord(acc.ID);                    
                    acc.count__c= totalcount;
                    lstAccounttoUpdate.add(acc);
            }
            /*//**** TRY ->Once all Triggered records done with their count updates-
            // In the end run this to traverse hierarchy and update counts accordingly.
            for(ID aid: Child_To_TopAccount.keySet()){
                totalcount = getCountofCustObjRecord(aid);
                //if(mapAccountCustObjRecord.get(aid) == null){
                //mapAccountCustObjRecord.put(aid).of_Ref__c= totalcount;
                //lstAccounttoUpdate.add();  ---HOW to take record from MAP<id,id> into list<account> //UPDATE MAP itself
                // }
            }
            */
            if(lstAccounttoUpdate.size()>0){
                update lstAccounttoUpdate;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){            
            system.debug ('ERROR:CustObjRecordTriggerHelper=> updateNoOfCustObjRecord:' + e);
        }
    }


      //Method to get Top Level Parent Account in Hierarchy
    public static Map<ID,ID> getTopParentAccount(Set<ID> AcctIds){
        Map<Id,Id>Child2Parent = new Map<Id,Id>();
        List<Id> Accnts = new List<Id>(); 
        Accnts.addAll(AcctIds);
        Set<Id>Acts2 = new Set<Id>();
        Acts2.addAll(AcctIds);

        While(Acts2.size() > 0)
        { 
            List<Account>accnts2 = [SELECT ID, ParentId FROM Account WHERE ID IN :Accnts ]; 

            for(Account a:accnts2){
                if (a.ParentID != null) {  
                    //put record into map 
                    Child2Parent.put(a.Id,a.ParentId);
                } else if(a.ParentID == null) {
                    //remove account with parent from list of accounts to query
                    //since this means parentId == null
                    Acts2.remove(a.Id);
                }

            }

             if(Acts2.size() == 0) break;   
             Accnts2.clear();
        }
        // return map of accounts 2 ulitmate parent account
        return Child2Parent;

    }


    //Method to get count of Self CustObjRecord and immediate Child Accounts Referrals
    private static Decimal getCountofCustObjRecord(ID acctid){
         // Need to traverse Child Account Trail - to generate Level & Details Map
         getChildAccountsInHierarchy(acctid);

        Decimal count=0;
        for(ID accid : accountIdLevelMap.keySet()){
                /* $$$$ --- THIS MIGHT BE CAUSING AN ISSUE ---- $$$$  --- 0 & 1 Levels count only.
                 * but thought of adding so BECAUSE -> One should get count of CustObjRecord from its immediate childs 
                 * and himself
                 */
                if(accountIdLevelMap.get(accid)==0 || accountIdLevelMap.get(accid)==1){
                    count += accountDetailsMap.get(accid).of_Ref__c;
                }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void getChildAccountsInHierarchy(Id parentAcctId) {

        Boolean endTraversing = false;
        Integer accountLevel = 0; 
        String query;
        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        Set<ID> parentIdList = new Set<ID>();


        parentIdList.add(parentAcctId);

        while(!endTraversing) { 
            // observe closely at the WHERE clause, that's the key
            if(accountLevel == 0) {
               query = 'select Id, Name, ParentId, from Account WHERE Id IN :parentIdList';
            } else {
               query = 'select Id, Name, ParentId from Account WHERE ParentId IN :parentIdList';
            }
            acctList = Database.query(query);

            if(acctList.size() == 0 ) {
               endTraversing = true;
            } else {
               parentIdList.clear();
               acctList.sort();
               Account a;
               for(Integer i = 0; i < acctList.size(); i++ ) {
                   a = acctList.get(i);
                   parentIdList.add(a.Id);

                   // populate the account id and level and details maps to be later used
                   accountIdLevelMap.put(a.Id, accountLevel);
                   accountDetailsMap.put(a.Id, a);

                   if(accountLevel > 0) {
                       // create the map of parent and related child accounts
                       // this is the key part of the iteration which takes
                       // care of adding the parent and related child
                       if(parentChildLinkedListMap.get(a.ParentId) == null) {
                           parentChildLinkedListMap.put(a.ParentId, new List<Account>()); 
                       }
                       parentChildLinkedListMap.get(a.ParentId).add(a);
                       parentChildLinkedListMap.get(a.ParentId).sort();
                    }
               }
               accountLevel++;
            }
        }

        // populate the list in the way they appear in the hierarchy
        addChildAccountsToList(parentAcctId);
        System.Debug('--------accountHierarchyList---'+accountHierarchyList);
        //return accountHierarchyList;
    }

    private static void addChildAccountsToList(Id parentAccountId) {
        Account a = accountDetailsMap.get(parentAccountId);
        accountHierarchyList.add(a);

        // get all associated child accounts for this parent from the map populated
        // then call the method recursively till the last node of the account is reached
        // below we add records in order of their appearance in tree
        List<Account> childAccounts = parentChildLinkedListMap.get(parentAccountId);
        if(childAccounts != null) {
            childAccounts.sort();
            for(Account acct : childAccounts) {
                // recursion
                addChildAccountsToList(acct.Id);
            }
        }        
        // finally return to get out from the stack
        return;
    }
}
```

- (please execuse for the messy Code)

Comment: How is Acc3's count = 1 while Acc5's count = 0 before you insert `CustObjRec13`? Both are leaf nodes in your hierarchy. Shouldn't the before counts be Acc1 = 2, Acc2 = 2, Acc3 = 0, Acc4 = 2, and Acc5 = 0, and the updated counts be Acc1 = 3, Acc2 = 3, Acc3 = 0, Acc4 =2, and Acc5 = 1?

Comment: That Count__c is not updated all the time with structure I am asking for -- THIS IS NEW REQUIREMENT  ---- (because its there/updated/manually done- only with no.of child account has on itself)

Comment: Ah, I see now. The `Acc1, Acc2, Acc3 can also have one CustObjRecords each` made me think that these accounts **could** have a `CustObjRecord` associated to them, and not that they **do** have a `CustObjRecord` associated to them. Now that I know these records **do have** associated records, the counts make sense.  I see that they were left out of your diagram for sake of being able to keep the diagram readable and reasonably short.

Comment: "Will Start bounty on this one in an hour-- Need urgent solution"

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue for a project that I was on last year in which I was dealing with managing the blocks of IP Addresses that my company controls. In my case, the hierarchy could be up to 17 levels deep (with some 2^16 possible records indirectly related to a single block of IP Addresses).

You really have 2 issues to tackle in this question:

1. How do I get a count of all `CustObjRecords` directly related to this account?
2. How do I get a count of all `CustObjRecords` related to child accounts?

For the sake of this answer, I'll assume that the relationship between accounts is a field called `Parent_Account__c` (self-relationships must always be lookup relationships), and the relationship between your `CustObjRecord` and `Account` is a master-detail relationship on `CustObjRecord` called `Account__c`.

I'll also assume that you have 3 fields on `Account`, `Direct_Count__c`, `Indirect_Count__c`, and `Total_Count__c`. `Total_Count__c` would simply be a formula field that adds `Direct_Count__c` and `Indirect_Count__c`.

In this situation, you can make a rollup summary field to count the number of `CustObjRecords` directly related to each `Account`.

If `Account` and `CustObjRecord` have a lookup relationship, you could accomplish this step by using [Andrew Fawcett's Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary Tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

That takes care of the first part. The second part is a bit...thornier.

If you have the Master-Detail relationship between `CustObjRecord` and `Account`, or if you're using the declarative rollup summary tool, you will have a trigger fired on `Account` before/after update.

Supporting a hierarchy of arbitrary height means that traversing up the hierarchy using `Parent_Account__r` multiple times is not viable (limited to 5 levels). Using additional queries for each level of the hierarchy is also ill-advised (queries are a precious resource!).

You could possibly use the declarative rollup summary tool for this part as well, but that would still use 1 query per level of your hierarchy.

To allow for a hierarchy of arbitrary height, you'll need an additional piece of information. You'll need to, on every `Account` record, keep track of the Id of the root of the hierarchy. This could be a lookup field, or it could simply be a text field. I'll call this field `Root_Account__c`.

This will allow you to use a single query to grab all of the records that will need to be updated (and potentially several that don't).

The general structure of your `Account` trigger will look something like this:

1. Loop through trigger.new, and build a `Set<Id>` containing the Ids of the hierarchy roots involved
2. `Map<Id, Account> accountsWithChildren = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Direct_Count__c FROM Child_Accounts__r) FROM Account WHERE Id IN <set of root ids> OR Root_Account__c IN <set of root ids>]);`
3. Use some good, old-fashioned recursion to calculate the `Indrect_Count__c` for each level in a top-down manner (not using recursion, and working this bottom-up is possible, but a lot more work)

The recursive bit could look like this:

```
public Integer calculateIndirectTotals(Account startingAccount){
  Integer indirect = 0;

  for(Account child : accountsWithChildren.get(startingAccount.Id).Child_Accounts__r){
    indirect += calculateIndirectTotals(child);
  }

  // The map<Id, Account> below is declared outside of this method
  accountsToUpdate.put(startingAccount.Id, new Account(Id = startingAccount.Id, Indirect_Total__c = runningTotal));

  return runningTotal + startingAccount.Direct_Count__c;
}
```

Now, as is, this code would likely run into some issues (`accountsToUpdate` probably includes the account(s) that are part of the update trigger that kicked off this method, which would lead to a SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER exception), but the basic idea should be sound.

**+edit:**

After I had written my answer, it was revealed that there are some additional constraints:

- A rollup summary field can't be used on `Account`
- We can only touch the trigger for `CustObjRecord`

The constraint that only the trigger for `CustObjRecord` can be touched is the most disruptive. If `Count__c` needs to be kept up to date in near real-time, then the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool is no longer a viable option (as it needs its own trigger on the child object to function in real-time mode, and order of trigger execution, when there are multiple triggers on an object, is not guaranteed).

**If you can live with updating `Count__c` on a looser schedule**

That is to say, not real-time (or near real-time). In this case, you're probably best served by the bottom-up approach using batchable (or queueable) apex as mentioned by crop1645 and Ratan.

The idea here is that you have a field on `Account` that keeps track of whether or not that `Account` needs to be updated. Initially, the trigger on `CustObjRecord` (for newly inserted, or updated, records) will aggregate the `Accounts` related to the `CustObjRecords` taking part in your trigger, and DML update those `Accounts`.

From there, you schedule a batch job. The batch Apex needs to end up running two queries

> [SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Id) FROM CustObjRecord WHERE Account__r.Update_Account_Count__c = TRUE GROUP BY Account__c]

and

> [SELECT Parent_Account__c, SUM(Total_Count__c) FROM Account WHERE Parent_Account__r.Update_Account_Count__c = TRUE GROUP BY Parent_Account__c]

The first query takes care of calculating `Direct_Count__c`, and the second query takes care of calculating `Indirect_Count__c`.

Finally, you update the `Accounts` taking part in the current batch job, setting their direct and indirect counts and, very importantly, unset `Update_Account_Count__c`. You'll also need to set `Update_Account_Count__c` for the parent accounts of the `Accounts` taking part in the current batch job. Then, you chain the next batch job in the `finish()` method of your batch apex class.

If everything goes right, the batch jobs will continue to chain until you reach the top of your hierarchy. Each new batch in the chain is in its own execution context, so you won't run into the 100 SOQL query limit by virtue of the batch apex alone.

**If you need the counts updated as soon as possible**

Then you'll need to expend a few more queries to get things set up.

`CustObjRecord's` trigger will need to do the work of updating the `Direct_Count__c` of the `Accounts` related to the records in your `CustObjRecord` trigger. That particular query is simple (gather affected accounts, use `COUNT(Id)` to query/count all the `CustObjRecords` related to those accounts, dml update).

The code to calculate `Indirect_Count__c` can easily be put into `CustObjRecord's` trigger instead of `Account's` trigger. The only difference is that you'll need to query for the `Root_Account__c` of the affected accounts instead of being able to grab that information from a trigger context variable.

**+edit2:**

**That's all well and good, but how can I identify the Account at the top of the hierarchy?**

In my original answer, I mentioned having a field `Root_Account__c` on every `Account`. This field isn't automatically populated, you'll need to have a plan to maintain the integrity of this field going forward, and you'll need to figure out a way to update your existing accounts so that they contain this information.

If `Root_Account__c` is a text field, a simple workflow rule set to run on creation every new `Account` with a field update to set `Root_Account__c` to `Parent_Account__r.Root_Account__c` (or to its own Id if it doesn't have a parent) would take care of adding new leaf nodes and roots. You still have other cases to worry about (deleting the root, deleting another non-leaf node, adding a new node above the current root, etc...), but handling those cases would be a separate question. This doesn't populate `Root_Account__c` on your existing accounts, however.

Without touching `Account's` trigger, your best bet to accomplish both tasks is probably a batch job that is called via another class that implements the `Scheduleable` interface (so that your batch job is being regularly run). You can schedule a batch job to run once via `system.ScheduleBatch()`, which I imagine can be done through executing anonymous apex in the developer console.

The batch class here would work top-down. The query for the batch could look something like this:

> [SELECT Id, Parent_Account__r.Root_Account__c FROM Account WHERE (Parent_Account__c = null AND Root_Account__c = null) OR (Root_Account__c = null AND Parent_Account__r.Root_Account__c != null)]

This would pull the `Accounts` at the top of your hierarchies which haven't been set up to support the other group of `Accounts` that this query also pulls, the set of `Accounts` which don't have `Root_Account__c` set but have a parent that does.

Those null values in the query are problematic though. It will make the query slow, and it will outright fail from not being a selective query if you have enough `Accounts` (>= 100,000)

A better way to do this would be to do a little more prep work.

- create one more field on `Account`, a checkbox field which I'll call `Needs_Root_Populated__c`, and defaulted to true.
- With anonymous apex, query for all the root `Accounts` (those with no parent), set `Root_Account__c` to their own Ids, and unset `Needs_Root_Populated__c`

The query can then become

> [SELECT Id, Parent_Account__r.Root_Account__c FROM Account WHERE Needs_Root_Populated__c = true AND Parent_Account__r.Needs_Root_Populated__c = false]

This won't pull new root accounts, but the query should be much more selective.

The last thing left to do is to use that query to update the `Accounts` that were pulled, and then to chain another batch so this process continues down to the last leaf node in your hierarchies.

This makes the `Root_Account__c` information available at all levels of your hierarchy. You simply need to query for this field on the `Accounts` whose `Direct_Count__c` is being updated in `CustObjRecord's` trigger.

Comment: interesting, I had this problem too once and did it with a chain of batch jobs (could be queuable now) that (0) processed leaf nodes first, then (1) parents of leaf nodes next, then parents of nodes from (1), and so on until there was nothing left to do. Not as fast as triggers but requirement could be met by nightly job

Comment: Yes Same I did this with batch jobs

Comment: "Will Start bounty on this one in an hour-- Need urgent solution"

Comment: Can you explain how the answer I've provided doesn't solve the issue presented in your question?

Comment: I can't use Rollup summary fields.  (there is some sort of business reason)  AND I need to do this by writing trigger on "CustObjRecord" ONLY. 

(Do Rollup Summary works with Personal Accounts ?)

Comment: That's some very important information that should be included in your question. Please edit your question to include that. I'll work on editing my answer to reflect those constraints.

Comment: You can [always make rollups work](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Comment: Agree with this ----(by derek - "need the counts updated as soon as possible ---- The code to calculate Indirect_Count__c can easily be put into CustObjRecord's trigger instead of Account's trigger. The only difference is that you'll need to query for the Root_Account__c of the affected accounts instead of being able to grab that information from a trigger context variable.") --- That's what I am not able to code.  Following blog might help in someway - 

https://sfbypeter.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/managing-multiple-multilevel-account-hierarchies-efficiently-in-apex/

Comment: One more doubt --- Can this be done using "Process Builder - which will initiate Flow" ???

Comment: I'll work on expanding the section on grabbing the root/top level account. I have no experience with the Process Builder, so I can't say for certain, but my gut feeling is no.

Comment: The Process Builder [isn't](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlPBAA0) triggered on delete.

Comment: @NileshMendhe Have you taken a look at my updated answer yet?

Comment: Yes I certainly did ! Thank you so much for your help.  I will accept your answer as solution, will also post my final Code (not too optimized - but for reference ) in a while

Comment: @salesforce steps would you mind posting your final code?